# WebBrowser control to Trigger application page navigation

Tags: navigation, browser, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to trigger a navigation inside the application not the webbrowser when clicked on a link inside webbrowser control?

For example you can use the following link to open cellular settings page of os.

`<a href="ms-settings-cellular:" >Launch Settings</a>`

I tried `<a href="/MainPage.xaml">Open main page</a>` but did not work.

I wonder whether is it possible without writing code or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relative navigation - **no**. However, if your application registers a URI scheme, you can leverage that, and have something like **myapp:SecondaryPage**. Details on the implementation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: +1. HTML links can't navigate the RootVisual frame. Register for the WebBrowser.Navigating event and use C# to do the navigation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also listen for the [WebBrowser.ScriptNotify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.scriptnotify%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) event if you can insert some JavaScript in the page.